# docker.service: No such file or directory

Tags: docker, vagrant

I just updated to the newest versions of Vagrant and Docker on my Mac. When running `vagrant up --provider=docker`, I get the following error:

```
==> default: Configuring proxy for Apt...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

sed -e 's/\[Service\]/[Service]\nEnvironmentFile=-\/etc\/default\/docker/g' /lib/systemd/system/docker.service > /tmp/docker.service

Stdout from the command:

Stderr from the command:

sed: can't read /lib/systemd/system/docker.service: No such file or directory
```

This was all working on Vagrant 2.2.4 before I updated to 2.2.9. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Not a proper solution, but reverting back to Vagrant 2.2.4 solved the issue. I still have no idea why this is the case though.